# ffmpeg libtwolame mp2 how set options like mode or copyright

Tags: ffmpeg, stereo, mono

How I can change the audio mode (and other option flags) for libtwolame (mp2) encoder in ffmpeg?

I've tried with

```
ffmpeg -f jack -i ffmpeg -r 48000 -c:a mp2 -mode "m" -b:a 128k
```

and also

```
-mode 'm'
-mode "mono"
-mode 'mono'
```

but the encoded stream is in stereo - always.
...Also, other options seem not to work, like "copyright" and "original" and others...

Comment: Share full command and log.

Answer (score 0):

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:a libtwolame -mode mono -copyright 1 -original 1 output.mp2
```

- Make sure your `ffmpeg` was compiled with `--enable-libtwolame`. You can check this by executing the plain `ffmpeg` command and referring to the `configuration` line in the output.
- If you want to encode with libtwolame you have to use `-c:a libtwolame`.
- `-mode`, `-copyright`, and `-original` are private options only for libtwolame, so they will be ignored by the native FFmpeg MP2 audio encoder (`-c:a mp2`).
- See `ffmpeg -h encoder=libtwolame` and [FFmpeg Codecs Documentation: libtwolame](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libtwolame) for more options.